# What does the `-O99` flag do?

Tags: haskell, ghc

The title is a slight joke.

I just discovered today that `ghc` accepts any optimization level without complaining.  I know that `-O2` is supposed to be the maximum optimization level, and that there is a proposed `-O3` [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1371), but I was just curious what happens when you mistakenly specify an even higher optimization level.  Does `ghc` default to `-O2` or does it not optimize at all?

Comment: If memory serves, a nonexisting optimisation level was ignored by old(er) GHCs, and since a couple of years, `-On` with `n >= 2` becomes `-O2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it is clamped to be between 0 and 2 in [`compiler/main/DynFlags.hs`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/460abd75c4f99d813ed226d2ff6aa592d62fafd4/compiler/main/DynFlags.hs#L1748):

```
updOptLevel :: Int -> DynFlags -> DynFlags
-- ^ Sets the 'DynFlags' to be appropriate to the optimisation level
updOptLevel n dfs
  = dfs2{ optLevel = final_n }
  where
   final_n = max 0 (min 2 n)    -- Clamp to 0 <= n <= 2
   ...
```